# Check if pandas dataframe is correctly increasing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to verify if there are outliers in the column of a dataframe knowing that it must be increasing or decreasing

For example the dataframe `df_bad` is growing and its data is the following:

```py
df_bad = pd.DataFrame([1,2,-3,1,5,8,7],index=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60])
```

The correct dataframe should be corrected to:

```py
df_correct = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],index=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60])
```

where it is identified that the indices 20,30 and 50 are incorrect because the value of the row `df_bad.loc[20]` is less than the value of the previous row, the value of the row `df_bad.loc[30]` is greater than its previous row, however, is not greater than the highest correct value (`df_bad.loc[10]`), the value of row `df_bad.loc[50]` is greater than its previous row, however, it is also greater than its next row.

If possible I would like to correct the `df_bad` dataframe as best as possible to the `df_correct` dataframe. It should be noted that only in the example the increasing steps are one at a time, and that the dataframe that I want to correct has more columns with the same trend.

If it cannot be correctly corrected, a `df_checked` dataframe could be created where the atypical data is changed to zero and is subsequently filled in with the average of the adjacent ones or, if possible, with the trend to create the dataframe `df_fixed`.

```py
df_checked = pd.DataFrame([1,2,0,0,5,0,7],index=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60])
df_fixed   = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3.5,3.5,5,6,7],index=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called cumulative max to see whether a value is greater or lesser than all the previous values and make those values nan.
After that you can simply interpolate like this.

```
df_bad[df_bad[0].cummax() != df_bad[0]] = np.nan

df_bad[0] = df_bad[0].interpolate()
```